How to do the fluid typography trick in tailwind?
I have always used this line in my vanilla css projects
html {
  font-size: calc(100vw / 1920px * 10px);
}

body {
  font-size: 3rem;
}

this makes my life easier to i design with figma at 1920 so if an element is 100pixel i know it's 10rem and it scales accordingly if i make the window bigger or smaller
i'm trying to add the same thing in tailwind but it does not seem to be working
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

html {
  font-size: calc(100vw / 1920px * 10px);
}

body {
  font-size: 3rem;
} 


I'm sorry to confirm this. I've just tested the CSS code you have always used in your vanilla CSS projects but it didn't work too. So I think this is the reason why it also didn't work in Tailwind. Have you tested the original one yet?

@haptn you're absolutely right my syntax was wrong
the correct syntax with css should be
html {
font-size: calc((100vw / 1920) * 10);
}
the old syntax only work with sass, appreciate your observation
